# imageIO_PNG_Dataのメモリ使用量が多い

Tags: objective-c, iphone

アプリ内でカメラロールから画像を選択して、コレクションビューに表示できるようにしています。

ですが、画像を表示するとメモリを多く消費してしまいます。
Instrumentsで調べるとimageIO_PNG_Dataが原因だということはわかったのですが、どのように直せばいいのかがわかりません。

[image: Instruments(画像は今回4枚です)]

```
//カメラロールを起動
- (void)showCameraRoll
{
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType
    = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = sourceType;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}


//カメラロールから画像選択後の処理
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"画像選択後の処理");
    UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *editImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    UIImage *saveImage;

    if (editImage) {
        saveImage = editImage;
    } else {
        saveImage = originalImage;
    }

    //カメラで撮った写真のみカメラロールの保存
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(editImage, nil, nil, nil);

    [self addSelectedPicture:self item:saveImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}


//画像保存処理
+ (void)saveLessons:(NSArray *)lessons
{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:lessons];  
    NSString *path = [self makeLibraryPath];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

+ (NSString *)makeLibraryPath
{
    NSArray *paths =     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.dat"];
}
```

どなたか何か分かる方がいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

コレクションビューに取得した画像を表示するということは、フルサイズのイメージである必要はなく、サムネイルといわれる、せいぜい100×100ピクセルくらいのイメージであればいいんですよね？だとすれば、フルサイズのイメージを用意すれば、それ相応にメモリを消費するのは道理だと思います。メモリ消費を抑えるには、コレクションビュー用に小さいサイズのイメージを作成するプログラムを書く必要があると思いますが、以下のサンプルコードは、iOS 8より導入された[**Photos Framework**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html)を使った、サムネイルイメージを作成して、取得するものです。
`UIImagePickerController`のDelegateメソッドのみ載せています。Photos Frameworkを使うために、`#import <Photos/Photos.h>`をインポートしてください。

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
    // イメージピッカーで選択したイメージのリファレンスURLを取得。
    NSURL *imageURL = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    // イメージのアセットassetを取得。
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs: [NSArray arrayWithObject: imageURL] options: nil];
    PHAsset *asset = fetchResult.firstObject;
    // 指定したサイズ（仮に72×72）のイメージを生成して返すことを要求。
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset: asset targetSize: CGSizeMake(72.0, 72.0) contentMode: PHImageContentModeAspectFit options: nil
        resultHandler: ^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
            // 取得したimageを使用するプログラムを、ここに書きます。
    }];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: NULL];
}
```

Comment: 回答していただき、本当にありがとうございます。
おっしゃるとおりでコレクションビューに表示するための画像にPhhotosFrameworkを使ってサムネイルを取得して使用したところ、メモリを大幅に抑えることができました。ありがとうございます。
ですが、質問が十分じゃなく申し訳ないのですが、コレクションビューに選択し表示させた画像をタップすると次のビューで大きく見れるようにしたいのです(標準のカメラロールのような感じで)が、この場合は次のビューでの表示のみフルサイズのイメージにすることはできないのでしょうか。
お願いします。

Comment: できなければ、Appleがあたらしくフレームワークを作った意味がありませんよね？まずは、Photos Frameworkの概要を勉強なさって、そのうえで不明な点を、新規に質問なさってください。